# Change the color of the table row based on the value from sercer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am creating a JSP page with a html table to display employee directory. This is scriptlet :

```
      <%
            String selectedItem = "";
            List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            PhoneListController controller = new PhoneListController();
             list = controller.getAllContacts();
            }
            for (Employee eachEmp : list) {

        %>


           <tr >
                <td><%=eachEmp.getLast()%></td>
                <td><%=eachEmp.getFirst()%></td>
                <td><%=eachEmp.getExt()%></td>
                <td><%=eachEmp.getLoc()%></td>
                <td><%=eachEmp.getCell()%></td>
                <td><%=eachEmp.getTeam1()%></td>
            </tr>

<% } %>
```

and then i display the table rows and columns for each employee object(PS: I know scriptlets are bad and obsolete but this is my first individual project.)

I would like to change the background color of certain rows based on value of one particular value(based on eachEmp.getManagerCode).

How can i achieve that by using javascript? I tried to call a js function by calling onload event on . But as I need to check for each row that is not the possible solution. I have not tried jquery yet as I am very new to jquery and I didnt quite understand how to do it in jquery.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Your scriptlet stops short of showing how you format the html for eachEmp. Although the easy trick would be to set this managerCode as an attr on row, jquery can then just check that attribute on all rows and assign a color using a simple switch.

Comment: I added the table row code above. Could you please elaborate on adding managerCode as attribute?

Comment: Your values are getting set on the server side, by JSP code. You know whether a row represents a manager before the page is served. So, there is no reason to solve this problem on the client side (by using JS or JQuery). Using a simple JSP if, you can add a CSS class to the row (<tr class="manager_row"> if eachEmp.getManagerCode indicates that you should, and just a plain <tr> if not.  I'd recommend googling "clientside vs serverside" (without the quotes) and making sure you understand where each part of your code is being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use an if statement

```
 <%
        String selectedItem = "";
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        PhoneListController controller = new PhoneListController();
         list = controller.getAllContacts();
        }
        for (Employee eachEmp : list) {


          if (eachEmp.getManagerCode==1) {    %>
        <tr class="red">
       <% }   else   {   %>
       <tr class="blue">
       <%   }    %>

            <td><%=eachEmp.getLast()%></td>
            <td><%=eachEmp.getFirst()%></td>
            <td><%=eachEmp.getExt()%></td>
            <td><%=eachEmp.getLoc()%></td>
            <td><%=eachEmp.getCell()%></td>
            <td><%=eachEmp.getTeam1()%></td>
        </tr>

<% } %>
```

Or if you don't want to use css class you can simply write  etc.. etc..

you can put how many if you want, or use the switch statement